# LabVIEW disabled Slider is enabled

Tags: slider, labview

I have a large problem disabling a slider in LabVIEW. Here is my minimal example:

I have a simple Slider, which is disabled and grayed out if the value is higher than 5. Otherwise the Slider is enabled.

[image]

If I drag the slider higher than 5, the Slider gets grayed out. But I am still able to move the slider around and change the value. Only after I dropped the Slider, the Slider is disabled to use.

In my opinion, this is a large bug of LabVIEW. Is there any way to disable the Slider correct during drag?

Thank you for your answers!

**Additional information:**
Like I said, the snippet is only my minimal example to show the basic problem. In my application the following is happening:

I have s statemachine with a state that enables the Slider and a state that disables my Slider. The state can change every moment, so it´s possible, the user is using the slider at the moment of statechange --> moment of disabling. At this moment the slider should be disabled (it only gets grayed out) directly ... not after releasing it. So limiting the maximum is not real target. I want to prohibit all slider actions for a user.

"[Link to question asked on NI Discussion Forums](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/disabled-Slider-is-enabled/td-p/3285087)"

Comment: As part of LV R&D, I'll grant "bug" but not "large bug". It's a pretty bad user experience to rip the control out from under them just because they happen to jiggle their mouse past a certain threshold, so I would not expect most user interfaces to use this pattern. I suggest you wait until a Mouse Up event tells you the user is done dragging the pointer.

Comment: I can't really understand what you want to achieve anyway, from a user experience perspective. The user can adjust the control to any value below 5, but if they go above 5 the control becomes disabled? What value do you want the control to take after that happens? What happens next in the program?

Comment: @srm I added some additional info to my question. This should describe my problem better.

Comment: @nekomatic I added some additional info to my question. This should describe my problem better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Alexander_Sobolev on the NI forum (but I promise I thought of it independently!), you can end the slider drag by generating a mouse up event. On Windows you can do this with `Simulate Mouse.vi` [from the NI site](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-36012), which calls `mouse_event` from user32.dll:

[image: VI snippet showing use of Simulate Mouse.vi]

Note that one of that VI's mouse position inputs is erroneously marked as 'Required'; I fixed that before creating the code above.

I do think this is a UI technique that should only be used if it's really justified by the requirements of the system, and if the users will understand why it works like that; otherwise it could make for a frustrating and annoying user experience. I don't think it's a bug, rather a design decision, because the opposite behaviour could be equally undesired in other circumstances.

Comment: This works, so I am voting it as the solution, but for any future readers, you may want to consider a UI design where "user moves the slider and then clicks a 'Commit' button separately." This design would mean that the user change of a value is a single moment event that can be locked by moment-to-moment system changes of graying out the button without surprising the user's experience. Using the slider control directly as the question wants to do is really only recommended for values that the user can change continuously meaningfully.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could set the slider value to 5 inside the case structure, alongside the greying out, by adding another property node. This should keep the slider stuck at 5, if the user tries to pull it above.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be strange behavior as the Value Change event is triggered while the mouse button is held down even when the control is Disabled & Grayed Out.

One way I can think of to limit the value would be to update the Data Entry Limits Maximum property for this control and setting the Response to Value Outside Limits for Maximum to be Coerce.
[image]